# How to find a number in a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string like - "you can enter maximum 500 choices".
I need to extract `500` from the string.

The main problem is the String may vary like "you can enter maximum 12500 choices".
So how to get the integer part?

Comment: You should click the check mark by the answer given by cletus. It was more than sufficient.

Answer (score 156):

Use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

```
const r = /\d+/;
const s = "you can enter maximum 500 choices";
alert (s.match(r));
```

The expression `\d+` means "one or more digits". Regular expressions by default are [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) meaning they'll grab as much as they can. Also, this:

```
const r = /\d+/;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const r = new RegExp("\\d+");
```

See the [details for the RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

The above will grab the **first** group of digits. You can loop through and find all matches too:

```
const r = /\d+/g;
const s = "you can enter 333 maximum 500 choices";
const m;
while ((m = r.exec(s)) != null) {
  alert(m[0]);
}
```

The `g` (global) flag is key for this loop to work.

Comment: Minor typo with the backslash in the string:

var r = new RegExp("\d+"); 

should be 

var r = new RegExp("\\d+");

Comment: the 1st regular expression works. The second one (`RexExp(...)`) doesn't.
Thank you @bambam Just saw your comment after I figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 40):

```js
var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = "you can enter maximum 500 choices";
var matches = string.match(regex);  // creates array from matches

document.write(matches);
```

**References:**

‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ [regular-expressions.info/javascript.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220719183920/https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html))

‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220719183937/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp))

Answer (score 18):

```js
const str = "you can enter maximum 500 choices";
const result = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
console.log(result); // "500"
```

playground: https://regex101.com/r/1ADa3c/1

Answer (score 11):

I like @jesterjunk answer, 
however, a number is not always just digits. Consider those valid numbers:
"123.5, 123,567.789, 12233234+E12"

So I just updated the regular expression:

```
var regex = /[\d|,|.|e|E|\+]+/g;

var string = "you can enter maximum 5,123.6 choices";
var matches = string.match(regex);  // creates array from matches

document.write(matches); //5,123.6
```

Comment: Did try your regex? It matches any `e` character (or any other characters you have in that list, "E", "," or "."). For your input `matches` is `[ 'e', 'e', '5,123.6', 'e' ]`

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this :

```js
var string = "border-radius:10px 20px 30px 40px";
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(numbers)
```

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd add my take on this since I'm only interested in the first integer I boiled it down to this:

```
let errorStringWithNumbers = "error: 404 (not found)";        
let errorNumber = parseInt(errorStringWithNumbers.toString().match(/\d+/g)[0]);
```

`.toString()` is added only if you get the "string" from an fetch error. If not, then you can remove it from the line.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = "you can enter 30%-20% maximum 500 choices";
var matches = string.match(regex);  // creates array from matches

document.write(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// stringValue can be anything in which present any number
`const stringValue = 'last_15_days';
// /\d+/g is regex which is used for matching number in string
// match helps to find result according to regex from string and return match value
 const result = stringValue.match(/\d+/g);
 console.log(result);`
```

> output will be 15

If You want to learn more about regex here are some links:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_regexp_object.htm

Answer (score 0):

Now this is very easy to do using the ***'replace'*** method and ***'regexp'***. For example:

```js
findNumber = str => {
  return +(str.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
}

console.log(findNumber("you can enter maximum 500 choices"));
console.log(findNumber("you can enter maximum 12500 choices"));
```