# How to find number inside [] Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following syntax.

```
 var name =  [Name_is][234]

   var number = find [234];
```

How can i find this number in javascript/jquery which is inside `[]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: Jimmy is you found duplicate post please Delete your question, before it gets answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
var string = "[Name_is][234]"
var matches = string.match(/\[(\d+)]/);

if (matches.length) {
    var num = matches[1];
}
```

Check out a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEJ5V/, and read more on the [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Comment: There are no (apparent) strings in the question.

Comment: @Quentin: I can't see what else they'd be. A string is my best guess.

Comment: I was thinking it was some sort of "find index of value in array" question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract the text between the `[ ]`, you can do:

```
var name = "[Name_is][234]";
var check= "\{.*?\}"; 
if (name.search(check)==-1) { //if match failed
  alert("nothing found between brackets");
} else {
  var number = name.search(check);      
  alert(number);
}
```