# Match decimals from a string with regex

Tags: regex, gwt

I want to get two decimals from a string using a Regex but I get only the first.

`getGroupCount` is correct but I get always `{1}` and I don't know why. I'm using GWT 2.5. Here is my code:

```
private void readOffset(){
    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("(\\{\\d\\})");

    MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec("(cast({1} as float)/{24})");

    String val1 = matcher.getGroup(0);
    String val2 = matcher.getGroup(1);
}
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: You are using package RegExp and MatchResult from  com.google.gwt.regexp.shared package on gwt client side code?

Comment: If you are expecting gwt client side code help then you should remove regex/java tag. GWT Regex is different!!!!!

Comment: from com.google.gwt.regexp.shared package

Answer (score 1):

The operator `\d` will only yield 1 digit. If you want to get two, you would need to use `\d{2}`. If you need to match more, you would need to use `\d+`, where `+` means 1 or more repetitions of.

Something like so worked for me (Java though, not exactly GWT):

```
        String str = "(cast({1} as float)/{24})";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\d+\\})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);         
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Yields: `{1}` and `{24}`

Comment: Apart from that, he's confusing groups with matches

Comment: i changed to \d+ but i get still the same group.

Comment: @user1573659 I have added some extra Java code which should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: GWT Regex implementation is different from normal regex. Normal java answers probably may not work

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to use Regex in GWT client side please go through the Unit test cases in GWT for Regex. Reference - [GWT Unit Test for Regex](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Also you should be using RegExp and MatchResult from **com.google.gwt.regexp.shared**.

Comment: Can you just not replicate this in GWT - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

im to stupid for the regex so i solved it quick and dirty:

```
private void readOffset(){
    String offset = manager.get("offset");

    String v1 = offset.substring(offset.indexOf("{")+1, offset.indexOf("}"));
    String v2 = offset.substring(offset.lastIndexOf("{")+1, offset.lastIndexOf("}"));

    multiplikator.setValue(v1);
    divisor.setValue(v2);

    /*
    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(".*({\\d+}).*", "g");
    MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(offset);
    boolean matchFound = (matcher != null);

    if(matchFound == true && matcher.getGroupCount() == 2){
        String val1 = matcher.getGroup(0);
        String val2 = matcher.getGroup(1);

        multiplikator.setValue(matcher.getGroup(0));
        divisor.setValue(matcher.getGroup(1));
    }else{
        multiplikator.setValue("1");
        divisor.setValue("1");
    }
    */
}
```

better solutions are welcome :(