# How to extract number from string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am to trying to extract numbers from string for example

```
East Texas Baptist University (582) (COL)

North Central Texas Academy (202471) (COL)

Bloomfield College (1662) (COL)
```

I have used parseInt but it gives me NAN. Can any one please suggest a better way. Thanks

Comment: Is the string always in this format? If so, you can use regex..

Comment: You could use a regexp ;)

Comment: Possible dublicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [strip non-numeric characters from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string)

Comment: Yup string will be always in this format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for that like:

```
"Bloomfield College (1662) (COL)".match(/(\d+)/)[0] //1662
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function getNumber(str) {
    return parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
}
```

You can use the function like this:

```
var num = getNumber('East Texas Baptist University (582) (COL)');
```