# JQuery Regex - get the number inside of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do I extract the number inside of a string like the examples below?

```
myform-5-id
myform-32-id
myform-0-id
```

The number will always be an integer >= 0, and the text will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that you are looking for is `/\d+/`.

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\d+` matches one or more numbers
- The surrounding `/` is the way to mention the regex pattern

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var r = /\d+/;
var s = "myform-5-id";
alert (s.match(r));
```

[Demo on Regex101 with explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/gA4kQ4/1)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt();

```
var int= parseInt('myform-5-id'.match(/[0-9]+/), 10);
alert(int);
```

This is an actual number and not a string.

Comment: first `op` want to regex solution and second your code incorrect, return `NaN` output

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non regex solution than you can use this otherwise @Rahul answer is perfect

```js
var a="myform-5-id";
var res=a.split('-');
alert(res[1]);
```