# Regex to retrieve numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

var string = "look1_slide2";

I would like to extract the the look number ie `1` and the slide ie `2` and save them in two different variables, I guess I could do it with a Regex but not sure how. Any help? The string will always have that format btw

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? it's very simple `var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g);` Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jgbsnzpn/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find a number in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: I guess the main problem here is not the regex but variable assignment, right?

Comment: well yes, but I think I still need to use  a hash so the page is bookmarkable.

Comment: Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdhhjbz1/).

Comment: Play around on https://regex101.com/, matches are your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string is always in that format you can simply read second and third entries of the returned regex matches array :

```
var string = 'look1_slide2';
var regex = /look(\d)_slide(\d)/g;

matches = regex.exec(string);
console.log(matches[1]);
console.log(matches[2]);
```

See [RegExp.exec() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/exec)

Comment: If OP does not need to return multiple matches with captured groups, why use `exec`? I think `match` is enough here (without `g` modifier).

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = "#div-name-1234-characteristic:561613213213";
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("");
alert (numb);​
```

This will print 1234561613213213

Comment: Hi, thanks, but how can I save them both in two different variables?

Comment: The thing is how  your number is represented? if your string pattern is look1_look2 then you can easily know that after '1' there is special character means no other number. You can differentiate numbers with this logic. 1 followed by '_' means 1 is alone and 2  followed by null character means 2 is alone save it with different variables. i.e Check the end of each number if next character is not number save into variable.