# How to find numbers in the following string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split

I'm trying to split a string in two parts with the separators "T" & "L".

`T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863`

So, I'm expecting an array with these elements:

["49.80000305175781","60.00000190734863"]

I have tried these but they don't work.

```
    var xPos = xPos.split('T', 'L'); //Returns empty
    var xPos = xPos.split(/T/, /L/); //Returns empty
    var xPos = xPos.split(/T/); //Returns: ["", "49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863"]
```

What should be the best approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find a number in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with a positive lookahead.

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863'.split(/(?=[TL])/));
```

Or without the letters, just a split where the letters appears.

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863'.split(/[TL]/));
```

Just for completeness, a proposal with [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in a single step

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863'.match(/[^TL]+/g));
```

Comment: Why is there an empty result at the beginning? (in the 2nd example)

Comment: that it the part in front of the `'T'`.

Comment: @Mjukis: You could take a look here, for how to filter out empty values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/1166642

Comment: you can apply `array.shift()`, then the first element is gone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+\.\d+/g`

```js
console.log("T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863".match(/\d+\.\d+/g))
```

Comment: This is actually the most flexible and the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Split takes two optional arguments. First one is the delimiter while the second one is the limit. You can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the documentation.

If you want to split it with multiple delimiters you should use a regex:

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863'.split(/T|L/));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ninas answer is great! I really mean it. But just to make it interesting if you would have more of these numbers/arrays or what ever you want to call it you could use a similar way like Nina, but use regular expression for letters to get all the values without the need to declare all of the letters.

With the letters included:

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863C34.534623460304040003'.split(/(?=[a-zA-Z])/));
```

Without the letters:

```js
console.log('T49.80000305175781L60.00000190734863C34.534623460304040003'.split(/[a-zA-Z]/));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use split with multiple separators like that.

What you can do is use a regular expression to split the string.

```
xPos.split(/T|L/g)
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the character with blank character and store that string into new variable. You will get all the number