# Is there a standard or recommended way to use parts of values in JSON that are separated by colons?

Tags: javascript, json

I use this API that returns a JSON with strings in values that are separated by colons.Example:

```
{
  "id": "test:something:69874354",
  "whatever": "maybe"
}
```

In this example I only need the numeric value of the identifier (69874354), but it could be that the value I'm after is a string (like 'something').
I've never seen this notation in APIs before and I know I could do something like:

```
var array = Object.id.split(':');
return array[array.length - 1];
```

...but it feels wrong and I'm thinking there is a standard behind this or a best practice I'm missing?

Comment: There is nothing in JSON standards that attempts to deal with the *value* of a `string` property. You'll have to deal with it manually and it's completely fine.

Comment: maybe you api offers some other flags to get another format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a number in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @adiga thanks but although the example uses numbers, the question extends to all data types.

Comment: what's wrong with using `split`? Is there any "pattern" for the item you want to isolate?

Comment: @molamk nothing wrong really, just that I thought the notation looked like a sub-sub value, some JSON wizardry I wasn't aware off, but it seems not to be the case (as pointed out by haim770 so... I guess I'll go with split.

Comment: do you have in all properties this style or only in some?

Comment: @NinaScholz only some.

Comment: do you know the keys in advance?

Comment: @NinaScholz it seems the info I'm looking for is always at the end but that's only those that I've seen until now. The second value (between column 1 and 2) seems to almost always be a copy of the parent object's key. If we're in an array, the value would be singular but otherwise the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it is correct, although it could be simplified:

```
return Object.id.split(":").pop();
```

Since as shown in the documentation for [`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), it returns the element `pop`ped from the array (the last element).

One suggestion with your code - don't use the name `Object` because that's reserved in JavaScript - use something else (`object` would be fine since JS variable names are case-sensitive).

Comment: Thanks Jack. I had forgotten about pop(), that's helpful. And yes the use of 'Object' was really for my explanation, it's not used in my code ;-).

Comment: No problem @BoDex, I'm glad I could help.