# JavaScript - Value of div is greater than, so do something

Tags: javascript, html

When price (value) in div `.highlight dd` is greater than **750**, insert element from `var` somewhere

```
var CustomOrderText = "<div class='CustomOrderText'>XY</div>";
```

if there are additional questions, I will be happy to specify. Please do not delete this post (as before). This is a very important question for me.

Edit: *I can´t remove "HTML entity" for space from the price, because I can't interfere in the generation process of the application that makes up HTML

```js
var CustomOrderText = "<div class='CustomOrderText'>XY</div>";
$(CustomOrderText).insertBefore("div.target");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="sumPrice withVat highlight ">
  <dd>779,70&nbsp;Kč</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem of your issue - this is a string `779,70 Kč` (Not number).
No way to find numbers that is greater than "hello" for example - one way is to use regex (Very modular). Related Q: [How to find a number in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript/30160994).

Less modular idea is to use [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

commas to your thousands (the string manipulation should be different):
[How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

```js
var number_with_commas = '1,125';
number_without_commas = number_with_commas.replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(number_without_commas);

/* jquery example */
var price = $(".price").text().replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/Kč/g, '');
console.log(price);

if(price > 750){
  console.log("price is higher than 750 - do something");
}
```

```html
<p><span class="price">779,70&nbsp;Kč</span></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you advice, but I can´t remove or edit HTML, because I can't interfere in the generation process of the application that makes up HTML. I can use just CSS and JavaScript

Comment: This price: `779,70` is 779.70 Kč or 77970 Kč?...in numbers.

Comment: It is 779.70 Kč (only hundreds)

Comment: So your real Q is how to convert `779,70 Kč` to `779.70`

Comment: I need to make JavaScipt that in case the price is higher than 750 CZK, insert var with sentence on div.target

Comment: so, it is about "if" contidion for value price higher than 750

Comment: I edit the answer  - take a look again. About the insert of Div X -or- Y you should edit the Q (No way to know what are you trying to do).

Comment: Looks like it works, Great job, thank you :)